# Angular2 : ContentChildren+QueryList error

Tags: angular

I want use @ContentChildren in Angular2 to navigate in a wizard.
But when i use it, i have this error : "zone.js?fad3:158 Uncaught Error: Can't construct a query for the property "steps" of "ExtendedWizard" since the query selector wasn't defined."

**wizard.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ContentChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'extended-wizard',
    template: `
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let step of steps">
                    {{step.title}}
                </li>
            </ul>
            <ng-content></ng-content>
    `
})
export class ExtendedWizard {
    @ContentChildren(ExtendedStep) steps: QueryList<ExtendedStep>;
}

@Component({
    selector: 'extended-step',
    template: `
        <fieldset>
            {{title}}
            <ng-content></ng-content>
        </fieldset>
    `
})
export class ExtendedStep {
    title: string;
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<extended-wizard>
    <extended-step title="Step 1"></extended-step>
    <extended-step title="Step 2"></extended-step>
</extended-wizard>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to move the class declaration `export class ExtendedStep` above it's first use, otherwise it will not be recognized. (only if you have several classes in the same file).

If you move

```
export class ExtendedStep {
    title: string;
}
```

just below the `import`s, it should work.

Comment: Oh my god! Thank you